# How to get a report of all the objects in a huge Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bigdata, google-cloud-storage

I have a bucket with multiple levels of folder within which 10000s of files under it (and growing). I'm wondering if GCS has a way to export a csv report of the entire bucket?

For example, AWS S3 makes it available via their storage inventory. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html

The GCS storage api has a `/list` endpoint that can help in the interim but it doesn't seem like a scalable option when there are 10-100 million objects in a single bucket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `gsutil` you can save the result list to a csv file by running:

```
gsutil ls -r gs://[BUCKET_NAME] >> list.csv
```

This will only contain the full path to each object though, so if you want more information [Cloud Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-asset-inventory/overview) that was suggested by vtor is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

GCP provides [Cloud Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-asset-inventory/overview) as a similar service to S3 Inventory.

From docs

> The Cloud Asset Inventory export service allows you to export the
>   event change history of multiple assets during a given timeframe. The
>   exported event change history shows you all the create, delete, and
>   update events for the specifed assets over time.

Here is a [quick start](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-asset-inventory/quickstart-cloud-asset-inventory) and an [API](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/storage/v1/rest).

Comment: I tried this but it only seems to list top level assets or resources info i.e., buckets or VMs for example but not the objects under a bucket. Some more info here https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-asset-inventory-reverse-engineering-an-api/

`gcloud asset export --help` also has more info which also doesn't seem to indicate a means to export all the objects to a file.